# Avoiding styles for last element containing a certain class element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this following hierarchy, and this is used at several places (so to add a class to them via jQuery is not feasable).

```
<li class="paginable">
    <span id="step-1" class="done"></span>
</li>

<li class="paginable">
    <span id="step-2" class="done"></span>
</li>

<li class="paginable">
    <span id="step-3" class="done"></span>
</li>

<li class="paginable">
    <span id="step-4" class="not-done"></span>
</li>

<li class="paginable">
    <span id="step-5" class="not-done"></span>
</li>
```

On the basis of the class `done` on element `span`, I have to provide certain style to those `span[id^="step-"]` which are also having the class `done`.

But not including the last `span` with class `done`.

How can I exclude the last `span` with class `done`. The classes `done` and `not-dont` changes in order like a series of steps.

I've tried:
`span[id^="step-"].done:not(-- with lots of combinations of last child on parent as well as child --)`

But it won't work and I logically know why.

Any suggestions **CSS ONLY**? or should I go and add class everywhere it is switched using jQuery?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a css only solution is available.

Using jQuery

```
$('span.done[id^="step-"]').not(':last').css('color', 'red')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jvgy6nLq/)

Comment: For jQuery, I have to put this thing everywhere. If it's the only solution, I wonder?

Comment: @DanglingCruze probably you should wait for some other answer... what do you mean by everywhere... how is the elements created/updated

Comment: @DanglingCruze You can also look at mutation observers(need to see the browser support needed) to see whether the dom structure has changed if so run the script...

Comment: Well, mutation observers sounds like it will solve my problem. I'll try to see if that works out. Yet, I'm looking for a CSS Only solution. Will tick this answer if couldn't find any other/better solution. Thanks :)